# Cannot pass bootstrap table cell data to php?

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a web based inventory system. In my project i have a user management page and it has a table to view all the users.

```
+----------------------------------------+
+ username + user type +        +        +
+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
+  sample  +  sample   +  edit  + delete +
+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
+  sample  +  sample   +  edit  + delete +
+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
+  sample  +  sample   +  edit  + delete +
+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

It has two buttons to edit user type and to delete user from the database. i need to get username from this table to php script, to execute delete query. I tried this,

```
$(document).on('click','.remove' ,function(){
    var $item = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').html();
    console.log($item);
    <?php $username = <script>$item</script>?>
});
```

but i can't pass this 'username' variable to php. How to do this? Thank you :-)

Comment: Use **ajax call**   to pass variabile user nane to php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this you need to perform an ajax request like this:

```
$(document).on('click','.remove' ,function(){
    var $item = $(this).closest("tr").find('td:eq(0)').html();
    $.post("url/file.php", { // your php file
        username: $item
    }, function(data, status){
        // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)
    });
});
```

**PHP** side:

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
//Do whatever you want ...
echo "success";
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that

Comment: Can i post this variable to a function

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by Ajax, this is suggested for your code:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "data.php",//file wich has query select to db table
            data: {id:theid},//describe your data here
            dataType: 'json',// type of data that will you get (JSON/HTML).
            type: 'POST',//sending type (POST/GET)
            success: function(data) {
               //do change the select option
            }
        });
```

Goodluck!